# React JSX with component in variable does not sync props

Tags: reactjs

The `Scegli` component is assigned to the App `comp` variable and then rendered in App `render` as a variable. However, the props assigned don't work: if I type in the input box, the value is frozen.

What am I doing wrong?

If I just move the `<Scegli>...</Scegli>` directly into the render (without assigning to a variable) it works as expected.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Scegli from './components/Scegli';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      valore: 'Single'
    }
    this.comp = <Scegli value={this.state.valore} handleChange={this.setValoreHandler} />;
  }

  setValoreHandler = e => {
    this.setState({
      valore: e.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          {this.comp}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Scegli.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Scegli extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input value={this.props.value} onChange={this.props.handleChange} />
        Valore scelto: {this.props.value}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Scegli;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.comp` is declared once, at the component's mount and stays in that state. You are not updating/re-rendering it anywhere, that's why it remains unchanged.

> You could either:

- move the JSX component directly to render:

  ```
  <div>
      <Scegli value={this.state.valore} handleChange={this.setValoreHandler} />
  </div>
  ```

or

- update the class variable with every input change (not recommended though):

  ```
  setValoreHandler = (e) => {
      this.comp = <Scegli value={e.target.value} handleChange={this.setValoreHandler} />;
      this.forceUpdate();
  }
  ```

Comment: I understand, so the real props sync can be done only in the render method, right? I thought that when I bind a variable in a prop, they would be "in sync" under the hood automatically after the first declaration. Instead (if I'm not wrong) there is no "in sync" thing, it is the render method that every time is called takes care of passing the new props and "recreate" the virtual dom. This doesn't work with my variable comp, because it is not recreated in the virtual dom by render, right?

Comment: @edoedoedo It is created, but it's not getting updated since it's declared and updated only once in the constructor. Constructor is declared only once, before the component mounts. Anyways if you want to make sure your flow fits React standards, move it to the render.

Answer (score 1):

(I could be wrong) but when you define `this.comp` in the `constructor()` it is only loaded once with the default state. The `constructor()` is not called on re-render (similar to `componentWillMount()`). So that is why it is frozen as the updated state is never sent `this.comp`

Instead of `this.comp` in render do

```
return (
      <div>
          <Scegli value={this.state.valore} handleChange={this.setValoreHandler}/>
      </div>
    );
```